# Navigation Controller color RGB ios 9

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have figured out how to change the navigation controller to predetermined colors, but I can't figure out how to set it to RGBA. I found a bunch of answers for ios 7 that don't work anymore even after i converted the obj-c to swift.

This is the code that changes the nav controller, but id like custom colors

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @rmaddy this is what works so far, but i dont want to use xcode's colors i want to use custom colors                                                    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

Comment: As I said, update your question, don't put your code in a comment.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UIColor`? There is a clear method for providing RGBA values.

Comment: no ive been googling and searching stack overflow, but I will look for those docs

Comment: Always start with the reference docs. It's important to get to know the available APIs. Plus it gives you something to search for once you find something that seems to be what you need but you aren't sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this One :-

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 106.0/255.0, blue: 176.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: will accept in 4 minutes when it allows